# Synchronous XMLHttpRequest not Synchronous

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, xmlhttprequest, synchronous

The `send` method of `XMLHttpRequest` is not supposed to return until the response is received if the request is made synchronously ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#open())), but it does not appear that that is the case. My code works fine locally (with `--allow-file-access-from-files`), but when I put the files online and the content actually has to be downloaded, there are errors.

```
function loadXMLDoc(dname) {
    var xhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    else
        xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    xhttp.open("GET", dname, false);
    xhttp.send();

    return xhttp.responseXML;
}
```

The function returns `null`, but the content does eventually load (according to Firebug). It appears that the request is operating asynchronously even though I have specified that it be synchronous.

EDIT:
The error I get is just `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of null.` There is no "failed to load" message, and Firebug actually says when it's loaded and displays its contents.

Comment: You may get the content but you can't access or change it. Would you share that error?

Comment: The `response` usually is `null` when you're not allowed to access it (like in a cross-domain request). What errors exactly are there?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of null